# Heroku not finding express in server.js

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

Been having difficulty in deploying my react app to Heroku . I get the following error:

`ReferenceError: express is not defined`

Here the project structure:

- backend folder
- frontend folder
- package.json
- Procfile

Here is my Procfile

`web: node backend/server.js`

Here is the package.json in the root

```
  "name": "zippora",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.4.1",
    "npm": "7.18.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
    "jsonschema": "^1.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.0"
  }
}
```

My server.js file within the backend folder

```
const app = require("./app.js");
const { PORT } = require("./config");
app.use(express.static("../frontend/build/index.html"))
app.get("/", (res,req) => {
  res.send({"message":"Hello?"})
})
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

And the top of my app.js file within the backend

````
/** Express app for zippora. */

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const { NotFoundError } = require("./expressError");

const { authenticateJWT } = require("./middleware/auth");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users");

const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please, define express in the server.js

```
const express = require('express');
```

Your Server.js code become ...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = require("./app.js");
const { PORT } = require("./config");
app.use(express.static("../frontend/build/index.html"))
app.get("/", (res,req) => {
  res.send({"message":"Hello?"})
})
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(`Started on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I'll try that right now, thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That answered this specific error, thank you! On to the next issues

Comment: please vote this answer